# Ionic serve. Whats the difference between choosing localhost and Wireless network connection

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Multiple addresses available.

Please select which address to use by entering its number from the list below:

1. 192.168.1.11 (Wireless Network Connection)
2. localhost

Address Selection:

Whats the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0):

A localhost is always designated as 127.0.0.1.